# Implementation of insertion sort

Tags: optimization, c, sorting, insertion-sort

**Information about my code:**

I am following this [MIT OCW algorithms course](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/video-lectures/). The first lecture described insertion sort and merge sort. I implemented insertion sort in C.

The algorithm is structured as a function called from the `main` function. The array to be sorted is allocated dynamically in the `main` function but can also be statically allocated.

**What I am looking for:**

I am looking whether the code can be optimized without changing the algorithm (insertion sort), whether it follows the best-practices of programming in C and does it have proper readability factor?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void insertion_sort(int arr[], int length)
{
    /*
    Sorts into non-decreasing order
    To change the sorting to non-increasing order just change
    the comparison in while loop
    */
    register int j, k;
    int temp;

    for(j = 1; j < length; j++)
    {
        temp = arr[j];
        k = j - 1;
        while (k >= 0 && arr[k] > temp)
        {
            arr[k + 1] = arr[k];
            k--;
        }
        arr[k + 1] = temp;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int length;
    register int i;
    int *arr;

    //Finds the length of array and dynamically creates array of that length
    scanf("%d", &length);
    if ( (arr =  (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * length)) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Not enough memory");
        return 1;
    }

    //Reads the array
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);

    //Calls the sorting algorithm
    insertion_sort(arr, length);

    //Prints the sorted array
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);

    //Frees the memory allocated and returns
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort#Variants

Comment: @MarcDefiant Thanks for the link but instead of changing the algorithm I just wanted reviews about the currently implemented algorithm. Although they are variants of this algorithm they **are** different algorithms.

Comment: It'd be better if your sort was done on a linked list, as inserting elements to an array is very slow.

Comment: @VedranŠego I didn't understand what you said. Are you talking about the `main` function?

Comment: Sorry, I've mixed something up. Linked lists would make search slower, so the overall complexity would be O(n^2), just like in your case.

Comment: I get it now. You mixed up inserting elements into an array with insertion into linked list. That would be slower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot offer any optimization, only a few comments on best practice (as I
see it). There's very little to say; the code is nice.

- Use of `register` is unnecessary (and hence rare).  The compiler may well
  ignore it and it probably has a better idea of what to put in registers than
  you or I.
- It is best to define variables nearer to where they are first used.  This
  reduces their scope and makes for easier reading. For example in
  `insertion_sort` I would do:

  ```
  for(int j = 1; j < length; j++)
  {
      int temp = arr[j];
      int k = j - 1;
      while (k >= 0 && arr[k] > temp)
      ...
  ```

  So I defined the loop variable `j` in the loop and `temp` and `k` at the 
  point of first use.  (This makes even more sense in C++ where an early definition incurs the overhead of a default construtor call.)
- Your while-loop could arguably be a for-loop.  A for-loop makes the loop
  conditions more immediately obvious, but in such a short loop it makes no
  difference.
- In `main` you cast the return from `malloc`.  This is necessary in C++ but
  not in C.  And on an error in system and library calls that set the global
  `errno`, such as `malloc`, I would use `perror("malloc")` which will print a
  relevant error message to stderr, instead of rolling your own with `printf` (which prints to stdout).
- Again your for-loops in `main` would be better defining loop variable `i`
  in the loop.  Also these loops should have braces:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
  }
  ```

  Strictly speaking braces are not necessary but they are considered good
  practice, as they prevent a class of error such as someone adding a printf:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
      scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
      print("%d", &arr[i]);
  ```
- For safety, you should always check user input before using it, such as
  `length` here.
- Your comments in `main` are really just stating the obvious and as such
  could be considered 'noise'.  The comment in `insertion_sort` on the other
  hand is more useful, although 'non-decreasing' and 'non-increasing' are odd
  ways to say 'increasing' and 'decreasing' respectively.
- Really nit-picking, I prefer a space after `for` and `while` and no space
  between brackets in the expression `if ((arr = malloc(sizeof...`

Comment: About defining temp and k inside the for loop. I don't know about C++ but in C wouldn't that have significant more overhead in case of outer loop iterating over large ranges? Also wouldn't declaring loop variables at the beginning of a function better if they are reused instead of declaring them again and again?

Comment: No, in C there is no extra overhead associated with exactly where you define a variable.  The compiler will handle such things optimally without your needing to care.  And defining a loop variable in each loop instead of once at the beginning of the function incurs absolutely no overhead. On the plus side though it reduces the scope of the variable, which is always good - the reader knows for sure that it is not used outside the loop in which it is defined.

Comment: Can you add something about `errno`. I haven't used it ot `perror()` before. In my code the output of overflow is shown on the console itself. Is that the correct behaviour? Also I have updated the code. Please give your comments about that.

Comment: Every process on Unix etc has a global error number variable named `errno` set by failing system/library calls. Take a look at the Wikipedia page on `errno` or look at the manual pages on your system (type `man perror`).