# Largest LCM of partitions of a number

Tags: c

Suppose there is a number **N** which can be divided into two positive non zero numbers **X** and **Y** i.e `N = X + Y`. There will be **N/2** pairs of **(X,Y)**.

I want to find the largest `LCM(Least common multiple)` of `X` & `Y`

> **Example** 
>   `5 = (1 + 4)` and `5 = (2 + 3)`
>   Since `LCM(1,4) = 4` < `LCM(2,3) = 6` the largest LCM will be `LCM(2,3) = 6`.

**CODE**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int lcm(int, int);
int main(void) 
{
     int counter = 0;
     int lowerBound = 0, upperBound, input, result; // input is the n
     printf("input = ");
     scanf("%d",&input);
     int max = -1;
     upperBound = input; // at first upperBound will be the input
     for(counter=0; counter < input/2; counter++) // we will iterate till the input/2 terms 
     {
         lowerBound++;
         upperBound--;

         // in every iteration we will compute the lcm of lowerBound and upperBound
         // so 1st iteration : compute lcm(1, n-1)
         // 2nd iteration    : compute lcm(2, n-2)
         // 3rd iteration    : compute lcm(3, n-3)
         // .......after ((n/2)-1)th iteration.....
         // if n is even     : compute lcm(n/2, n/2)
         // if n is odd      : compute lcm((n/2)-1, n/2)

         result = lcm(lowerBound,upperBound); // store the result

         if(result >= max) // if result is maximum update the maximum
         {
             max = result;
         }
     }

     printf("output = %d",max);
    return 0;
}

int lcm(int x, int y)
{
    int n1 = x, n2 = y;
    while(n1 != n2)
    {
        if(n1 > n2)
           n1 = n1 - n2;
        else
        n2 = n2 - n1;
    }
  return((x*y) / n1);
}
```

**OUTPUT 1**

```
input = 10
output = 21
```

**OUTPUT 2**

```
input = 11
output = 30
```

---

**UPDATE 1**

After [Aseem Bansal](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/26426/aseem-bansal)'s answer I try to find a more optimize way to solve the problem and i came up with this code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int input, result = 0;
    printf("Enter the input = ");
    scanf("%d",&input);

    while(input <= 0) // if input is negative ask again
    {
        printf("Enter a positive non zero number :");
        scanf("%d",&input);
    }

    int middle = (input/2);
    if(input%2 != 0) // if the input is an odd number
    {
        result = (middle * (middle+1)); 
    }

    else // if input is an even number
    {
        result = middle%2 == 0 ? ((middle-1) * (middle+1))
                               : ((middle-2) * (middle+2));
    }

    printf("result = %d",result);
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT 1**

```
Enter the input = 13
result = 42
```

**OUTPUT 2**

```
Enter the input = 12
result = 35
```

**OUTPUT 3**

```
Enter the input = 10
result = 21
```

**EXPLANATION**

As for any *odd* number the `middle` and `middle+1` are highest [coprime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers) numbers, so the [GCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) will be 1. Therefore `LCM` will be product of `middle` and `middle+1`.

But for any *even* number the `LCM` of `middle` and `middle+1` is 1. So we need to find the nearest coprime numbers. If `middle` is even then the nearest coprime numbers are `middle-1` and `middle+1` otherwise the nearest coprime numbers are `middle-2` and `middle+2`. The product will be the result.

**NOTE**

here `middle` is [floor](http://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/function-floor-ceiling.html) of (`middle`).

Can it be more optimized? Any review is welcome.

Comment: Please add a definition of LCM (LCM: the least common multiple of two numbers is the smallest number (not zero) that is a multiple of both).

Comment: Related [question on CS](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13101/find-out-the-largest-lcm-of-the-partitions-of-n).

Comment: @AseemBansal yes actually if you look closely one of the answer is given by me.

Comment: I noticed that. Just wanted others reading this question to know that.

Comment: Did you actually run this code? Because of `scanf("input = %d",&input);` it will give incorrect results.

Comment: @AseemBansal i just corrected it.

Comment: @AseemBansal as i don't have enough reputation i can't comment on your answer. Thanks to your answer i got a more easy solution http://pastebin.com/bkMdhKT3

Comment: I would suggest you to use euclid's algorithm, paste the code here as an edit to your question [like I have done here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28132/implementation-of-insertion-sort-optimization), explain the logic behind the else part because I am curious and make a habit of [accepting answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) if you like one. All your choices but all recommended.

Comment: If you add the explanation put it in your question as an edit. Otherwise the comments will be very messy.

Comment: @AseemBansal Ok i will edit my question and put up the answer. Now for the `else` part, after many test cases i observe that for the even numbers the highest partition LCM always lies between `lcm((input/2)-2, (input/2)+2)` or `lcm((input/2)-1, (input/2)+1)`.

Comment: Updated the answer for exact answer. Its better than calculating both of these LCM.

Comment: @tintinmj I rejected your edit because your current code calculates 3 LCMs while my answer explains how it can be done by calculating only one of them. You might need to read my answer's **EDIT3** again.

Comment: Updated answer. I think my last update on this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about the overall algorithm but there are better ways for finding LCM. You should use a different algorithm. Try [Euclid's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Implementations) to find the GCD.

Then calculate `result`(your LCM) in `main()` as

`result = (lowerbound * upperbound)/gcd(lowerbound upperbound);`

The problem with your LCM function is that subtraction isn't the best way for finding the GCD which you are currently doing. It will take too long. Just consider the case of `x = 1 and y = 100000`. It should be easy to see that number of subtractions is much higher in this case and the program would be **very** slow.

---

If you don't want to change the algorithm(which you should) then the least optimization that I can think is to not declare `n1` and `n2` separately in the function `lcm`. Just use x and y. Do the final division by the product in the `main` function. It will at least save you 2 variables.

---

**EDIT**

I came up with a much better optimization. In your main loop instead of going from the outside pairs i.e (1, n-1) to the inside pairs you would do much better by going from the inside.

**Example**

> `5 = (1,4)` and `5 = (2,3)`. The maximum is found at `5 = (2,3)`.
>
> `7 = (1,6)` , `7 = (2,5)` and `7 = (3,4)`. The maximum is at `7 = (3,4)`.

The answer is in the middle. You'll get it without a loop.

But there is a big problem. This reasoning works only for odd numbers. I tried writing down numbers on paper and solved it by hand. I'll need some more time to find out a pattern for even numbers.

But **for odd numbers** this is probably the best optimization.

**EDIT2**

In the `main` function instead of
`if(result >= max)` you should be using `if(result > max)`. What is the use of replacing the number with the same number? One less operation.

You don't need to initialize `counter` at the beginning. You are doing that in the `for` loop.

**EDIT3:**

**For the case of even numbers** the maximum lcm will be either `lcm((input/2)-2, (input/2)+2)` or `lcm((input/2)-1, (input/2)+1)`. It's easy to find which will be maximum without calculating both of them.

If `input/2` is even then `lcm((input/2)-1, (input/2)+1)` should be maximum otheriwse it should be `lcm((input/2)-2, (input/2)+2)`.

---

**EDIT After OP's Update 1**

How about this as a better code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int input, result;
    printf("Enter the input = ");
    scanf("%d",&input);

    while (input <= 0)
    {
        printf("Enter a positive non zero number :");
        scanf("%d",&input);
    }

    // (x % 2) used as a condition in C means checking x for odd number
    int middle = input/2;
    result = input % 2  ? (middle % 2 ? middle * middle - 4 : middle * middle - 1)
                        :  middle * (middle + 1);

    printf("Result = %d",result);
    return 0;
}
```

Removed unnecessary braces, spaces, comparisons and comments. Comments are needed but commenting obvious things is just noise. I prefer single space on both sides of operators.

Comment: i also thought about nested ternary operators, this minimizes the code but create readability issue. I like the `(middle * middle) - 4` it's for `(a+b) * (a-b)` but seeing this code only once someone will stumble, just a thought.

Comment: Seeing `(a + b) * (a - b)` will also lead people to think why if they don't know the logic behind it. So that should not be an issue. If you can explain that then you can also explain this.

Comment: If if-else is nested a lot to just decide the value of a variable that would create more readability issues. This makes things clear IMHO.